# How does Bazel's py_binary stamping work?

Tags: python, bazel

The docs say that the "stamp" parameter will "enable link stamping" and that it will "encode build information into the binary" and "stamp the build information into the binary"

But where does that information actually go, and how can I retrieve it?

It does not seem to be a simple search-and-replace, nor variable definition, nor environment variable, nor format-string variable.  Test python script:

```
BUILD_HOST="ASDF"
print("{BUILD_HOST}")
print(BUILD_HOST)
```

Build rule:
`py_binary(name="catself", srcs=["catself.py"], stamp=1)`

Output:

```
$ bazel run --stamp catself
INFO: Analyzed target //:catself (0 packages loaded, 0 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
Target //:catself up-to-date:
  bazel-bin/catself
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.083s, Critical Path: 0.01s
INFO: 0 processes.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 1 total action
INFO: Build completed successfully, 1 total action
{BUILD_HOST}
ASDF
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like stamping might not be enabled for `py_binary`. It should work for `genrule` though, so something simple like this should work:

```
py_binary(
  name = "foo",
  srcs = ["foo.py"],
  data = [":stable-status.txt"],
)

genrule(
  name = "copy_stable-status.txt",
  outs = ["stable-status.txt"],
  cmd = "cp bazel-out/stable-status.txt $@",
  stamp = 1,
)
```

`foo.py`:

```
build_info = {}
with open("stable-status.txt") as stable_status:
  for line in stable_status.readlines():
    key, val = line.split(" ", 1)
    build_info[key] = val.strip()
print("Build label is:")
print(build_info['BUILD_EMBED_LABEL'])
```

then:

```
$ bazel run foo --embed_label=foobar
Starting local Bazel server and connecting to it...
INFO: Analyzed target //:foo (17 packages loaded, 102 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
Target //:foo up-to-date:
  bazel-bin/foo
INFO: Elapsed time: 2.985s, Critical Path: 0.11s
INFO: 1 process: 1 linux-sandbox.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 6 total actions
INFO: Build completed successfully, 6 total actions
Build label is:
foobar
```

Or something fancier:

```
py_binary(
  name = "bar",
  srcs = ["bar.py"],
  deps = [":buildinfo"],
)

py_library(
  name = "buildinfo",
  srcs = [":buildinfo.py"],
)

genrule(
  name = "gen_buildinfo",
  outs = ["buildinfo.py"],
  cmd = r"""sed -E 's/(.*) (.*)/\1 = "\2"/' bazel-out/stable-status.txt > $@""",
  stamp = 1,
)
```

`bar.py`:

```
import buildinfo
print("Build label is:")
print(buildinfo.BUILD_EMBED_LABEL)
```

Comment: If it's not enabled for py_binary, that's very strange, because it It seems like special attention was given to py_binary's stamp attribute.  It has unique documentation and is is tri-valued, rather than boolean like other stamp attributes.  Meanwhile, genrule's stamp attribute isn't even documented!

Comment: It looks like stamping is enabled internally and the documentation is leaking out. See https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/9437 and also https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/4942 for genrule.stamp

Comment: Even though I used "stamp=1" in my example, we were looking for a solution that respected `--stamp` and `--nostamp`, so genrules don't seem to be viable for that.  Omitting `stamp` in a genrule is equivalent to `stamp=False`.